# Getting the content of remote txt file

Tags: objective-c, ios, http

I have some txt files on my server and i want to read the content of them trought the http.
I use nsstringWithContentsOfFile, but it rasises cocoa error 260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"

```
id result = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[request responseString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]  JSONValue];
```

But Nslogging of [request responseString] gives a valid url,that contains the files i need.
Maybe i just can't use this method to access remote files?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this won't work at all.  You need to use NSUrl, or better, use a package like ASIHttpRequest: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: I already use it, but in other part of my project.Wil try to use it here

Comment: ASIHttpRequest is a super great, minimal package, cannot recommend highly enough.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidParmenter has the right idea (and I am +1'ing it), and the fix you want to do is:

```
NSString * result = NULL;
NSURL * urlToRequest = [request responseString]
if(urlToRequest)
{
     result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: urlToRequest
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]  JSONValue];
}
```

The most important concept here is that you have to pass a valid NSURL object to that `stringWithContentsOfURL` method.

Or, if the file you are trying to open is actually a FILE on the local disk, pass a valid path in a NSString to `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error`.

I hope this info helps you out!